# How to remove hyperlink underline in Email Signature

Tags: html, email, gmail, signature, sign

i created Email Signature but hyperlink are visible How to remove  hyperlink underline in Email Signature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the behavior of Gmail. It converts any websites addresses in the signature are automatically converted into hyperlinks.

There is no setting that is currently available in Gmail that would turn off these hyperlinks. But there is another way.

Clicking the Compose Mail button would open a new compose mail window populated with signature. Now click the Pain Text option above the message text area to remove the hyperlink.

Follow [this](http://blogmines.com/blog/how-to-remove-automatic-hyperlink-in-gmail-signature/) link. Might be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to close all gaps between your img tag and the surrounding anchor tag in your html.

This code will show the little underlines.

```
<a href="https://www.example.com" style="border-width:0px; border:0px; text-decoration: none;">
                        <img width="25" height="25" style="vertical-align: middle; border: none; width: 25px; max-width: 25px !important; height: 25px; max-height: 25px !important;"
                            src="http://example.com/test.png">
                    </a>
```

This code won't.

```
<a href="https://www.example.com" style="border-width:0px; border:0px; text-decoration: none;"><img width="25" height="25" style="vertical-align: middle; border: none; width: 25px; max-width: 25px !important; height: 25px; max-height: 25px !important;" src="http://example.com/test.png"></a>
```